# PHP JSON array accessing

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have a PHP variable, let's say named $products

when I try to print the first element in that variable by printing $products[0], the array print the word (array) on the screen.

how I can access each element in this array? thank you

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2356
        [title] => REAR BRAKE
        [price] => $0
        [image] => 2356_BRS-10228-1.jpg
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2358
        [title] => REAR BRAKE MITSUBITSHI
        [price] => $0
        [image] => 2358_BRS-10230-1.jpg
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2360
        [title] => Axela CX-4
        [price] => $0
        [image] => 2360_BRP-10639-1.jpg
        [quantity] => 1
    )
```

)

Comment: [Accessing array elements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)

Comment: You can't `echo` or `print` arrays. You can echo or print [scalar types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) (and objects implementing the magic function `__toString()`). ]What exactly are you trying to do? Show us your code.

Comment: i want to print the elements of each array object.

Comment: $products[0] is also an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use foreach loop :

```
foreach($data as $key =>$value){
echo $value['id'].'<br>';
}
```

result :

```
2356
2358
2360
```